# Debugging Azure Function with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-functions-core-tools

I've been struggling to debug an `HttpTrigger` type azure function with vscode.

My assumption is that the issue might be related to the config files within `.vscode/` or at worst, my own environment.

As of now, when I try to debug a recently created function (func init) I get the following error from vscode:

```sh
> Executing task: dotnet clean /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <

execvp(3) failed.: Permission denied

The terminal process "dotnet 'clean', '/property:GenerateFullPaths=true', '/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary'" failed to launch (exit code: 1)
```

Inside `.vscode/` there 4 files:

```
    ├── extensions.json
    ├── launch.json
    ├── settings.json
    └── tasks.json
```

and inside task.json there are a few dotnet related commands that are causing the error above.

Despite these files being automatically generated by core tools (func) I removed the dotnet lines from task.json and hit Debug.

After a few seconds I get:

```sh
Failed to detect running Functions host within "60" seconds. You may want to adjust the "azureFunctions.pickProcessTimeout" setting.
```

Is there any command to automatically generate the debug configuration? e.g. `".NET generate assets for build and debug"`

Have you faced anything similar to it?

---

My env settings:

```sh
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Code:1.64.2 x64
Azure Functions Extension: v1.6.0
Core Tools Version: 3.0.3904
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the `type` from **process** to **shell** inside `tasks.json` solved it.

[image]

- FWIW, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4556